# How to block email to certain email addresses or domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

We have an application built in rails 3.2.8. We are sending emails to customers. I want to block certain emails addressses. Basically mailer just ignore those particular email addresses.

For example: My company name is abc and I dont want to send emails to all my employees ie john@abc.com or rayn@abc.com ie *@abc.com

How can I do this?

*PS: I am using sendgrid, they are not providing anything like this.*

**EDIT:**

Placing this code in initializers directory:

```
 class EmailAddressFilter
  def self.delivering_email(message)
    message.perform_deliveries = false

  end
end

ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(EmailAddressFilter)
```

Should block all the emails. But still I can see emails in my development log.

*PS: I have restarted my server.*

Comment: What exactly are you seeing in your logs? The email is still going to be rendered/built, and I would expect that to appear in the log.

Comment: @Deefour Ok lemme test it in production mode.

Comment: @Deefour worked on production server.. :) Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a file in `config/initializers` you can add something like this

```
class EmailAddressFilter
  def self.delivering_email(message)
    # permit or deny the message using its "to", "body" etc properties
    # note message.to is an array (multiple emails)
    message.perform_deliveries = Email.whitelisted?(message.to)
  end
end

ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(EmailAddressFilter)
```

Comment: NoMethodError (undefined method `match' for ["john@abc.com"]:Mail::AddressContainer):

Comment: That's just a *(simple)* example of how you might go about this. Your matching/checks would be much more elaborate and thorough. I added `.join("")` which I believe should make the error go away *(but it doesn't make the test complete IMO)*